# Prove by Laws of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$ [(A ÷ B)- C]$ U $(A ∩ B ∩ C)$ = $[A - (B ÷ C)]$ U $[B - (A ÷ C)]$
 where $A ÷ B$ = $(A-B)$ U $(B-A) $
By using Venn Diagram , I am sure both are equal.
I have to prove it by using Laws of Sets , but my calculation is getting too complex as I am trying to break it down and so I am stuck :(
L.H.S =  $[(A ÷ B)- C]$ U $(A ∩ B ∩ C)$
       = $[[(A-B)$ U $(B-A)] - C]$ U $(A ∩ B ∩ C)$
       = $[[(A ∩ B')$ U $(B ∩ A')] ∩ C']$ U $(A ∩ B ∩ C)$
                where $A - B$ = $(A ∩ B')$
I tried more, but it is becoming more complex , I am stuck now , could someone help me , Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Looking at one piece of the RHS:

$\begin{array}{ccc} A-(B\div C)&=&A\cap[(B\cup C)-(B\cap C)]'\\
&=& A\cap [(B\cup C)\cap (B\cap C)']'\\
&=&A\cap[(B\cup C)'\cup(B\cap C)]\\
&=& A\cap[(B'\cap C')\cup(B\cap C)]\\
&=&(A\cap B'\cap C')\cup (A\cap B\cap C)\end{array}$

Similarly, the other chunk of the RHS gives $B-(A\div C)=(A'\cap B\cap C')\cup (A\cap B\cap C) $

Based on this and what you did on the LHS in your question, I think you should be able to put it all together.

Comment: Thanks m8 , I got it :D

Answer (score 0):

let's call $a$, $b$, $c$ the predicates $x\in A$, $x\in B$, $x\in C$ respectively. Then

$x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A\land x\in B\iff a\land b$

$x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A\vee x\in B\iff a\vee b$

$x\in A'\iff \overline{x\in A}\iff \bar a$

$x\in A - B\iff x\in A\land x\in B'\iff a\land\bar b$

$x\in A\div B\iff x\in (A\cap B')\cup(A'\cap B)\iff (a\land\bar b)\vee(\bar a\land b)$

Using for the logical AND the justaxposition (that is, no symbol at all) instead of $\land$ and for the logical OR the symbol $+$ instead of $\vee$, and giving to the AND greater priority w.r.t. the OR, it results:
$$x\in[A-(B\div C)]\cup[B-(A\div C)]\iff a\left(\overline{b\bar c + \bar bc}\right)+ b\left(\overline{a\bar c+\bar a c}\right)$$
and
$$x\in [(A\div B)-C]\cup(A\cap B\cap C)\iff (a\bar b+ \bar ab)\bar c+ abc$$

then 
$\begin{equation}a\left(\overline{b\bar c + \bar bc}\right)+ b\left(\overline{a\bar c+\bar a c}\right)=a(\bar b+c)(\bar c+b)+b(\bar a+c)(a+\bar c)=\\=a\bar b\bar c\\+a\bar b b~~(=\operatorname{False})\\+ac\bar c~~(=\operatorname{False})\\+b\bar aa~~(=\operatorname{False})\\+b\bar a\bar c\\+bca\\+bc\bar c~~(=\operatorname{False})\\=\end{equation}(a\bar b+ \bar ab)\bar c+ abc$